# JSON error with Julia Dash simple example

Tags: csv, http, julia, plotly-dash, dataframes.jl

I've been trying to replicate the "A simple example" posted at https://dash-julia.plotly.com/clientside-callbacks

The server runs... but when I connect to it I get a JSON parse error in Firefox.

[image: error]

I was able to solve the problem, but I'd like to understand what's wrong...

The problem was this line inside the Dash app.layout:

`options=[(label = country, value = country) for country in available_countries]`

and the `available_countries` variable was obatined from:

```
read_remote_csv(url) = DataFrame(CSV.File(HTTP.get(url).body))
df = read_remote_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminderDataFiveYear.csv")
available_countries = unique(df.country)
```

Apparently the error showed because `available_countries` was an `Array{String31,1}:` and specifically the problem was the `String31` type.

when I converted the variable to a plain `String` type:

`available_countries = convert(Array{String,1},available_countries)`

the problem solved.

Now... I'm not sure if the `String31` type came from the `HTTP.get()`, `CSV.File()` or the `DataFrame()` functions.

I'm assuming the example used to work when it was originally written but it broke with an update...
Can anyone explain where exactly the error originates? Is it a Package version thing? which package? (HTTP, CSV, Dataframes)? How can I avoid it moving on?

Comment: `String31` is one of the primitive types made by `InlineStrings.jl` to avoid heap allocating `Strings`, and it was a recent development in `CSV.jl` (https://www.juliabloggers.com/fixed-width-strings-in-csv-jl/). I'm guessing the code example you tried was designed for plain `String` instead of `InlineStrings`. I can't say why this "control character" error happens now, though, your `InlineStrings` could be converted to `String` without invalid control characters, so the `InlineStrings` must be misinterpreted by `Dash` somehow.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Now... is there a way to tell CSV.jl not to automatically create columns of appropriate widths, and just use plain `String` as type?

Comment: In general, I would stick with as much InlineStrings as I could and convert to Strings so I only heap-allocate when I absolutely need to. That said, in this case the need seems pretty immediate, so use the keyword argument `stringtype = String` (doesn't hurt to check the documentation of a method or keyword arguments: https://csv.juliadata.org/stable/reading.html#CSV.File, https://csv.juliadata.org/stable/reading.html#stringtype).